# Unable to run plnkr for angular 4

Tags: angular, plnkr.co

I have plunger code below and this code is for showing some child Component :

HTML inside child component is shown below:

```
<div>
      <h3>I'm the Child component</h3>
    </div>
```

Plnkr code is shown below:

https://embed.plnkr.co/aYET8s/

But whenever I run the plunger, I am getting "Loading.." text.

Why am I not getting "I'm the Child component" in the browser?

Could you please help?

Comment: https://unpkg.com/rxjs/operators.js as "rxjs/operators" from https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js this package is not loading

Comment: how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `config.js` to use `rxjs@5` and `angular/core@5`

```
  map: {

    'app': './src',

    //'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@5/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

    //'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js'
  },
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/KJtulZ?p=preview)

Comment: Superb! It was incredible!